# What is this error? (Java database application)

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx

I have the following code and I'm trying to return data from my database (itemName, itemId). Yet it gives me the following error:

```
Items() in Items cannot be applied to:
Expected         Actual
Parameters:      Arguments:

pool: com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Pool     itemName (java.lang.String)
code: com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Code itemId    (java.lang.String)
symtab: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab     quantity (java.lang.String)
types: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types     cost (java.lang.String)
```

Here is my code:

```
public List<Items> getItemList() throws SQLException{
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Items");
        {

            List<Items> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

            while (results.next()) {
                String itemName = String.valueOf(results.getString("item_name"));
                String itemId = String.valueOf(results.getString("item_id"));
                Items items = new Items(itemName, itemId); // where the error is
                itemsList.add(items);
            }

            return itemsList;
        }

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Is it because the types are incompatible (object v. string)? If so, String.valueOf... incorrect?

***EDIT***

```
public class Items {

// Constructor
public Items(String itemName, String itemId){
    setItemName(itemName);
    setItemId(itemId);
}

// itemName
private final StringProperty itemName = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"itemName");

public StringProperty itemNameProperty(){
    return itemName;
}

public final String getItemName(){
    return itemNameProperty().get();
}

public final void setItemName(String itemName){
    itemNameProperty().set(itemName);
}

// itemId
private final StringProperty itemId = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"itemId");

public StringProperty itemIdProperty(){
    return itemId;
}

public final String getItemId(){
    return itemIdProperty().get();
}

public final void setItemId(String itemId){
    itemIdProperty().set(itemId);
}


}
```

Comment: What are the expected types of the arguments of constructor?

Comment: public Items(String itemName, String itemId)

Comment: Not sure where come that error format. so I will guess from what I understand from it that it expect 4 arguments, not two and seems to be other type than `String`, are you importing the good `Items` class ?

Comment: try adding items to your creation of the array list like
List<Items> itemsList = new ArrayList<>(Items);

Comment: Why did you use `String.valueOf()`? What are the data type of table columns?

Comment: @JasonD what are you expecting from that ? Blasanka, indeed not necessary but not important either, it will just assure this is a String not in the pool

Comment: am I the only one who has never seen a stacktrace in that fashion?

Comment: @Gianluca I am going over tutorials, then trying to write it myself without assistance so it's definitely possible I messed up...

Comment: @AxelH What do you mean by "importing the good Items class"?

Comment: I think @AxelH right. You need to overload the `Items` constructor.

Comment: @purpleman, I don't think so. It must be your implementation of the JVM. Anyway, I don't ask what it is as you're going through tutorials. Anyway, some thoughts, some of which have already been pointed out by others:
1. It seems you are invoking the constructor with the wrong arguments, but, again, that stacktrace is quite wierd. Can you post the complete stacktrace?
2. String.valueOf is useless as ResultSet.getString already produces a string

Comment: @Blasanka How do you do that? (newb)

Comment: @purpleman If you can provide `Items` class implementation, we can make sure what's happening.

Comment: @Blasanka Edited the post

Comment: @purpleman According to my knowledge `StringProperty` use in JavaFX. Is your program JavaFX?

Comment: @purpleman read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060633/difference-between-simplestringproperty-and-stringproperty) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266498/when-to-use-stringproperty-over-string).

Comment: @Blasanka I created the classes first in Java (tutorial for inventory management) then I wanted to add an interface to it so I looked at tutorials for JavaFX.... and added that material to my existing classes (modifiying a bit). As I said, I'm a newb and a bit in over my head... :/

Comment: Can you check your imports? Have you accidentally imported the wrong `Items` class (in the class containing the first block of code)?

Comment: @James_D Is it this? import com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Items THIS SOLVED IT!

Comment: Yes, that line is the problem.

Comment: @James_D Could you explain to me like a five year old the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @purpleman Added an answer. You can google "packages and imports in Java" for a basic explanation. A quick scan of [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm) suggests it may be good.

Comment: @Blasanka it has nothing to do with an overloading... he just import the wrong package. So indeed, the class don't find the constructor expected

Comment: @purpleman the answer is exactly what I meant by a bad import of class ´Items´.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an issue that is caused by importing an `Items` class from the wrong package. If you have an import statement of the form

```
import some.package.name.Items ;
```

near the top of the class containing your first block of code, then remove that line.

If the class containing the first block of code is in a different package to your `Items` class, then you need to add in a line

```
import the.correct.package.Items ;
```

in place of the incorrect `import` statement. Replace `the.correct.package` with the name of the package containing your `Items` class (in `Items.java`, look at the first line of code, which is a `package` statement defining which package contains `Items`).

For some background information, I recommend [Meaning of the import statement in a Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903166/meaning-of-the-import-statement-in-a-java-file)

Comment: Didn't get the confirmation before I had to leave. It was my guess too. About the package, note that the statement could be missing if it is in the unnamed/default package. Then, it can't be imported.

Comment: @AxelH Yes; sorry, didn't see your original comment. I was going to mention default packages too, but decided I didn't want to make it more complex... :). (It would seem unlikely that the OP put the first class in a named package and the `Items` class in the default package, which would be the only scenario where that was relevant, I think.)

Comment: I couldn't figure out it. It was a problem to me also! nice catch!

Comment: No need to apologize, I am cool with it ;) there is some good post asking how to import classes from that package, a link to one would remove the complexity but let you add that information before someone get that problem. But not sure this is really required here.